# I have data frame and column with dates looks like

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

```py
Date  
-1.476329  
-2.754683  
-0.763295  
-3.113292  
-1.353446
```

when I am trying to convert these -ve float values into `dd-mm-yyyy` , I am getting the year as 1969 or something with almost same date in every row. But the year should be near to 2018-2020

Comment: How are you converting these to the dates? Can you add/explain the algorithm or the code?

Answer (score 0):

Computers store time from 01 Jan 1970. Since you didn't gave insight about your algorithm I can only guess that when you convert your float values it uses this default value.

Maybe [Datetime defaulting to 1970 in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587468/datetime-defaulting-to-1970-in-pandas) will help ?

Answer (score 0):

As your dates should have years near to 2018-2020, probably your `Date` column contains number of years relative to now (or another base date).  As such, you can do:

Find out what base date the dates are relative to.  For demo purpose, I set it to today's date:

```
base_date = pd.to_datetime('now').normalize()
```

Then, derive the calendar dates from your `Date` column by multiplying 1 year duration by `np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')` and add the base date:

```
import numpy as np

df['Date_Derived'] = base_date + df['Date'] * np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       Date               Date_Derived
0 -1.476329 2020-01-05 18:45:56.610792
1 -2.754683 2018-09-25 20:56:40.793784
2 -0.763295 2020-09-22 05:05:36.323160
3 -3.113292 2018-05-17 21:26:33.794016
4 -1.353446 2020-02-19 15:56:09.543408
```

You can further truncate the time values by:

```
df['Date_Derived'] = df['Date_Derived'].dt.normalize()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       Date Date_Derived
0 -1.476329   2020-01-05
1 -2.754683   2018-09-25
2 -0.763295   2020-09-22
3 -3.113292   2018-05-17
4 -1.353446   2020-02-19
```