# MatPlotlib: X-axis start from year 1970 but is from only 2017

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, arima

I have dataframe with timestamp as index and price values as column. When I try to plot using `plot_acf`, the x-axis is starting from `1970`.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf

data = {'price_btc': {Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'): 1132.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'): 1142.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-06 00:00:00'): 1128.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-07 00:00:00'): 1164.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-08 00:00:00'): 1189.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-09 00:00:00'): 1188.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-10 00:00:00'): 1194.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-11 00:00:00'): 1208.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-12 00:00:00'): 1213.0,
               Timestamp('2017-04-13 00:00:00'): 1218.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Original Series
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 5))
axes[0, 0].plot(df.price_btc); axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
plot_acf(df.price_btc, ax=axes[0, 1])

# 1st Differencing
axes[1, 0].plot(df.price_btc.diff()); axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.price_btc.diff().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])

# 2nd Differencing
axes[2, 0].plot(df.price_btc.diff().diff()); axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.price_btc.diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])

plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Expected output is to have dates from 2017 in Autocorrelation plots as well.

Issue is with `sharex=True`. Need to have different x lables for autocorrelation plot.

Comment: When a timeseries starts at 1970, it is a sign that your datetime is not correctly imported into the pandas dataframe. See, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54914293/8881141) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37766686/8881141).

Comment: @Mr.T If I remove autocorrelation plots, everything seems to work fine. This is only happening when I add Autocorrelation plots and x-axis ranges from 0-100 for auto correlation plot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need `.diff().diff()` for second order differencing. You can give a integer as order to the `.diff()` method, so second order would be `.diff(2)`.

If you set `sharex = True` then all x-axis will be the same. The autocorrelation plot is not scaled by dates or so but by lags. Set `sharex = False` and add this line here for each plot to set the x axis:

```
axes[0, 0].set_xlim(dt.datetime(2017,4,4), dt.datetime(2017,4,13))
```

You can set the start and end date then.
Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {'price_btc': {pd.Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00'): 1132.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'): 1142.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-06 00:00:00'): 1128.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-07 00:00:00'): 1164.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-08 00:00:00'): 1189.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-09 00:00:00'): 1188.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-10 00:00:00'): 1194.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-11 00:00:00'): 1208.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-12 00:00:00'): 1213.0,
           pd.Timestamp('2017-04-13 00:00:00'): 1218.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Original Series
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=False, figsize=(20, 5))
axes[0, 0].plot(df.price_btc); axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
axes[0, 0].set_xlim(dt.datetime(2017,4,4), dt.datetime(2017,4,13))
plot_acf(df.price_btc, ax=axes[0, 1])

# 1st Differencing
axes[1, 0].plot(df.price_btc.diff()); axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order     Differencing')
axes[1, 0].set_xlim(dt.datetime(2017,4,4), dt.datetime(2017,4,13))
plot_acf(df.price_btc.diff(1).dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])

# 2nd Differencing
axes[2, 0].plot(df.price_btc.diff().diff()); axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
axes[2, 0].set_xlim(dt.datetime(2017,4,4), dt.datetime(2017,4,13))
plot_acf(df.price_btc.diff(2).dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Dates should be auto detected, cuz I have huge datasets and ranges can vary every time we check `plot_acf`. Is that possible to make this dynamic instead of hardcoding?

Comment: If you set `sharex=False` then the x axis limits and ticks will be detected automatically, what is the problem with that?