# How can I order dates and show only month+year on the x axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

I would like to improve my bitcoin dataset but I found that the date is not sorted in the right way and want to show only the month and year. How can I do it?

```
data = Bitcoin_Historical['Price']
Date1 = Bitcoin_Historical['Date']
train1 = Bitcoin_Historical[['Date','Price']]
#Setting the Date as Index
train2 = train1.set_index('Date')
train2.sort_index(inplace=True)
cols = ['Price']
train2 = train2[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str)
                     .str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))
print (type(train2))
print (train2.head())

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(train2)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylabel('Price', fontsize=12)
plt.title("Closing price distribution of bitcoin", fontsize=15)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The result shows picture below:

[image: result image]

It's not ordered and shows all dates. I would like to order by month+year and show only the month name+year. How can that be done?

Example of Data:

[image: result image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your data?

Comment: My dataset will consist of Date, Price, Open, High, Low, Vol., Change %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the following edits to your code:

- converted the column `Date` column as datetime type
- cleaned up the `Price` column and converting to float
- removed the line `plt.xlim(0,20)` which is causing the output to display 1970
- used alternative way to plot, so that the x-axis can be formatted to get monthly tick marks, more info [here](https://dataplotplus.com/change-datetime-tick-label-frequency-matplotlib-plots/)

Please try the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

Bitcoin_Historical = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
train1 = Bitcoin_Historical[['Date','Price']]
train1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(train1['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
train1['Price'] = train1['Price'].str.replace(',','').str.replace(' ','').astype(float)
train2 = train1.set_index('Date')    #Setting the Date as Index
train2.sort_index(inplace=True)

print (type(train2))
print (train2.head())

ax = train2.plot(figsize=(15, 5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Price', fontsize=12)
plt.title("Closing price distribution of bitcoin", fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: WOW. It's great. I got the results I expected.

Thank you so much

Comment: would you help to accept my answer please? (there's a tick mark on the left) Thanks :-)

Comment: I think I tick it for a long time. What tick that you mean?

Comment: sorry, I mean the green tick mark (ie, not the orange upvote arrow)

Comment: Ok, I tick it.
Sorry I don't know I can tick that mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast your "Date" column into datetime, check if it does the trick:

```
train1.Date = pd.to_datetime(train1.Date)
train2 = train1.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: It shows a year like '1970'. How can I change it? And would it be possible if I could only display the month and year?

Comment: yes, it is possible.  It seems your date format is '1-Apr-22'. Just add format='%d-%b-%y' to pd.to_datetime(train1.Date, format='%d-%b-%y'). As for display the month and year only, it is different topic, you can do it by train1.Date.strftime('%Y-%m')

Comment: I try to use pd.to_datetime(train1.Date, format='%d-%b-%y') but it still shows 1970.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587468/datetime-defaulting-to-1970-in-pandas check  this out

Comment: Thank you I got it with  train1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(train1['Date'], format = "%d-%b-%y").dt.strftime('%b-%Y')   but still try to order month because it's not sorted.