# Matplotlib pyplot condenses data for previous year

Tags: matplotlib, graph

I have python function which creates charts for 6 months data series.
Example of one function:

```
def result(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), dpi=150)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    data = data.sort_values(by='period', ascending=1)
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

    plt.plot(data['period'], data['result'], label='Result', solid_capstyle='round', marker='o', color='#92c6ff')
    plt.plot(data['period'], data['peer_result'], label='Peer Result', color='#5990C6', linestyle='--')
    annotate_chart(data['period'], data['result'].round(1))
    plt.legend(loc='upper center', fontsize=20, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15), frameon=False, ncol=4)
    plt.ylabel('(%)', fontsize=28, weight='bold')
    plt.xticks(data['period'], data['month'], rotation=45, fontsize=28)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=28)
    plt.title('Results', fontsize=28)
    plt.tight_layout()
    img = files_loc + '/result.png'
    plt.savefig(img)
    plt.close(fig)
    # Line fill graph placement
    pdf.set_xy(4, 30)
    pdf.image(img, w=105, h=75)
```

Dataset is in format:

| period | month | result | peer_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202308 | AUG | 82.14 | 83.22 |
| 202309 | SEP | 81.47 | 82.37 |
| 202310 | OCT | 82.87 | 82.53 |
| 202311 | NOV | 84.68 | 83.52 |
| 202312 | DEC | 83.26 | 82.58 |
| 202401 | JAN | 83.28 | 82.78 |

When I call function for full dataset (including January 2024), graph has condensed data for 2023:

```
result(data)
```

[image]

...but when I use only 2023 data, chart seems fine:

```
result(data.head(5))
```

[image]

When I try to call `result(data.tail(5))` the issue appears once again, so it's not connected to the size of dataset.
I tried converting data['period'] to numerical and categorical values - it doesn't work.

What can be an issue here?

I tried converting data['period'] to numerical and categorical values - it doesn't work.
I would expect the graph to present full data (including 2024) w/o modification.

Comment: Your `period` value is just being treated as a number, so the first five values are only separated by 1, while the last value is 89 greater that the penultimate one. In all the case where you currently have `data['period']`, just reoplace it with `range(6)` and it should look as you expect.

Comment: Alternatively (assuming `data` is a pandas `DataFrame`, you could convert the "period" column to a `datetime` format, e.g.,  `import pandas as pd;  data["period"] = pd.to_datetime(data["period"], format="%Y%m")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `"period"` data is just being treated as an integer, so the spacing you are seeing is what would be expected (i.e., the first fice values separated by 1 unit and the last one being 89 units later). You could instead [convert it to a `datetime` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) (assuming your `data` is a pandas `DataFrame`). A simple example would be:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "period": [202308, 202309, 202310, 202311, 202312, 202401],
        "result": [82, 81, 82, 85, 83, 83],
        "month": ["AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN"]
    }
)

# convert period to datetime format
data["period"] = pd.to_datetime(data["period"], format="%Y%m")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data["period"], data["result"])
ax.set_xticks(data['period'], data['month'], rotation=45, fontsize=14)
```

[image]

Also, when the "period" values are `datetime` objects, rather than manually setting the month x-tick labels from a column in the `data` object, you could instead do (see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957732/how-can-i-order-dates-and-show-only-monthyear-on-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib)):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "period": [202308, 202309, 202310, 202311, 202312, 202401],
        "result": [82, 81, 82, 85, 83, 83],
        "month": ["AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN"]
    }
)

# convert period to datetime format
data["period"] = pd.to_datetime(data["period"], format="%Y%m")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data["period"], data["result"])

# set x-axis formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

for label in ax.get_xticklabels(which='major'):
    label.set(rotation=45, fontsize=14)
```

[image]